# How to combine data from different rows of a csv in R?

Tags: r, csv, variables, rows

I have a dataset that links shoe-size with injuries. It's a csv file with a list of individuals, their shoe-size, and the number of injuries they had. I want to use R to make a linear model, plot their relationship and find the correlation between them.

The problem is, there are repeat entries. For example, there is a row with a person with shoe-size 8 and 2 injuries, and another row with shoe-size 8 and 3 injuries. When I try to plot the relationship from my data, it looks very strange, and I think this is why.

How can I combine all the people of the same shoe-size with their injuries, so that in the above example I'd have 5 injuries with shoe-size 8?

Another example (my actual dataset is much larger than this):

```
Name, Size, Injuries
A, 8, 5
B, 3, 1
C, 8, 2
D, 3, 3
E, 4, 2
F, 5, 3
```

I tried

```
plot(csv$Size, csv$Injuries)
```

and it has multiple values of injuries for sizes 8 and 3.

I want them to be combined so that Size 8 has 7 injuries, size 3 has 4 injuries, size 4 has 2 injuries, and size 5 has 3 injuries, so when I plot the relationship as I tried before there is only one injury value for each size, and the linear model and correlation is correct, so that I can also do:

```
lm(injuries ~ size)
cor(size, injuries)
```

correctly.

Comment: You can aggregate your data first like this: `library(tidyverse); data %>% group_by(Size) %>% summarize(Injuries = sum(Injuries, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Or use `aggregate(Injuries ~ Size, df, "sum")`.